# Django-signal receiver doesn't work although connected in the ready() method

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I'm new in Django, maybe my question has a simple answer, but I'm at deadlock. 
My signal code lives in `signals.py`, I use `@receiver`. According to documentations, I imported the signal submodule inside ready() in `apps.py`. But it doesn't work =( Could anybody help me?

N.B. If I write my signal code inside `models.py` everything works well.

Code:
`signal.py`

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
import os
from .models import ProductImage

def delete_image_from_storage(path):
  if os.path.isfile(path):
     print(path)
     os.remove(path)


@receiver(post_delete, sender=ProductImage)
def post_delete_image(sender, instance, **kawargs):
  if instance.photo:
      print(instance.photo.path)
      delete_image_from_storage(instance.photo.path)
```

`apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProductsConfig(AppConfig):
  name = 'products'

  def ready():
      import products.signals
```

`settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'products',
    ...,
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As explained in the FineManual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.11/ref/applications/#configuring-applications), you need to either explicitely register the appconfig in `INSTALLED_APPS` ie:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'products.apps.ProductConfig',
    ...,
]
```

or declare it as `default_app_config` in `products/__init__.py`:

```
# products/__init__.py
default_app_config = "products.apps.ProductConfig"
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I was inattentive! I thought that registered my app name in `INSTALLED APPS` was enough + I forgot to declare `self` in `ready()`